# lambda function to calculate weighted average in a group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have made the following line of code :

```
DF.groupby(["Name"], as_index=False).agg({"A": lambda x:sum(abs(x)) ,'B': 'first'}).round(2)
```

with a DF output :

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 6 | 3 |
| Test | -3 |  |

Gives the following output :

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 9 | 3 |

How would I do to get the following output :

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 9 | 1 |

1 given by the following formula :

```
((6*3)+(-3*3))/9 = 1
```

Wondering if it was possible to do this directly within the  group by

---

### Biggest DF##

```
Name    A   B
Test    3   3
Test    -3  2
Test    4   4
Test    5   5
Test1   6   7
Test1   7   8
```

The output would be :

| Name | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Test | 15 | 2.93 |
| Test1 | 13 | 7.54 |

Note :

```
A = Absolute value : Test = 3 + |-3| + 4 + 5 = 15
B = Weighted Average : Test = ( 3*3 + (-3)*2 + 4*4 + 5*5 ) / 15 = 2.93
```

Comment: Can you please add sample input to test from our end?

Comment: could you add one more row of data to help us understand your problem?

Comment: @shaikmoeed Please see the edit

Comment: @enke Please see the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use modify the columns using `assign`, then use `groupby.sum` find the totals; then `assign` again to find the ratio:

```py
out = df.assign(A=df['A'].abs(), B=df['A']*df['B']).groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum().assign(B=lambda x:x['B']/x['A'])
```

Output:

```
    Name   A         B
0   Test  15  2.933333
1  Test1  13  7.538462
```

Comment: Thank you v much, I also managed to make another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72204162/11167163). What do you think about it ?